# Google YouTube API (v3): how to access my unlisted/private videos from my server?

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

I've been experimenting with Google YouTube API (v3).
Until today, I used it with **public** videos.
Now I have the requirement to work with **unlisted** videos (for example, retrieve the list of my uploaded videos on a channel).
I see in the docs I should use [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) libraries.
This library requires an OAuth 2.0 client ID.
This library requires interactive authorization from client (it's oauth2, of course. Actually in the code samples is always included an *html* section.

Now the question is:

I need to access to **my** unlisted (or private, possibly) videos **server-side**: I would need an *unattended*, *server-to-server* kind of authentication.
Is it possible? If it is, then how?

Comment: If you just wanted to get the list of your uploaded videos, I think you could just use [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and set `forMine=true` (also making sure to specify `type=video`). That should return all of your uploaded videos, including those that are private or unlisted. I'm not sure if it also returns videos that you have scheduled that are not yet published.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Some annotations: with `forMine=true` parameter set, I get `error 400, reason: invalidSearchFilter`. Without it, I get a success response, but with 0 results (probably because my videos are `unlisted`). But, however, the problem is that this kind of access requires OAuth 2.0 **client** authentication, which is what I'm trying to avoid... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a refresh token in your server and request new access tokens from there going forward.

Otherwise, only if you have access to Content ID API, you can use service accounts and onBehalfofContentOwner parameter instead.

Comment: How long a saved refresh token will last? Does it expires?

Comment: How to create refresh token for server to server communication on behalf of owner of youtube channel? cant find it